# deploying sample django app on dotcloud using dcapp on windows 8.1 gave file not found error

Tags: python, django, dotcloud

I tried deploying the dotcloud sample diango app from a windows 8.1 pc, following the instructions on the dotcloud web site to the letter.

All went well up to the point of running:

```
dcapp myapp run "python manage.py syncdb"
```

which gave me:

> a file not found error [Windows error 2 The system cannot find the file specified]. No name was given for the missing file (maybe file name blank?)

The final message before the error was:

> File "subprocess.pyo" line 957 in _execute_child.

I can access the app from my browser, although it fails with a table not found error because the syncdb failed to run. I had also successfully deployed the sample flask app earlier form the same pc using the same command line tools and it went OK, although it's a very simple app with no database accesses.

I assume others trying to do the same thing would have had the identical problem, although I can't find any references to it. Is there a work-around for the problem, such as logging in directly to the dotcloud instance and running the syncdb there? As far as I can see, the webapp console doesn't allow this sort of thing. An SSH session maybe?

Comment: Digging a little further, the problem appears to be with any form of the dcapp run, including dcapp appname run bash. Seems like the windows version of dcapp is not good enough for deploying from widows.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks to Philipp Strube of cloudControl support. "On Windows it's recommended to run dcapp inside Git bash. Git bash is the easiest way to have a Unix like environment under Windows which the command line client depends on for some things including especially the dcapp run command, which relies on openssh being available."